# Material UI 5 MobileDatePicker year only, extracts 1 from the year

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, date-fns

Material UI MobileDatePicker with views=['year'] extracts 1 from the year.

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
    <MobileDatePicker value="2017" views={['year']} ... />
</LocalizationProvider>
```

When I set the value to "2017", the visible value in the input is 2016. When I open the picker the value is 2016 as well.
My time zone is **+00:00**. I think this is the reason of that extraction, It works fine when I set it to +03:00

```
new Date("2017").getFullYear()            // returns 2016
new Date("2017-02-02").getFullYear()      // returns 2017
new Date("2017").getUTCFullYear()         // returns 2017
```

in `new Date("2017")` the month and the day are Jan 1. This is why it returns 2016. While `new Date("2017-02-02")` the month is Feb and this is why it returns 2017

How I can give the value of "2017" and get the same value in the input with timezone +00:00 ?